# error with importing numpy in binder beta

Tags: numpy, import

I am trying to share my codes on Github using binder beta. The binder generate an environment however it generates Error on Importing numpy library. The Error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"
How may I solve the problem?

Comment: https://gitter.im/jupyterhub/binder; also, do you have a requirements.txt file to specify the environment (https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_repos.html#python-environment-with-requirements-txt)

Comment: thanks. The first time that I lunched the binder on my repository it worked well. However, now it does not. I think as you said It needs that txt file but I can not find that file. Is there any way to generate such a file? I guess that file has all libraries that are needed to run the codes.

Comment: You just write it yourself, in a text editor, based on the import statements being called and the version numbers you know the script to work with (otherwise, use recent versions). There is an example in the docs link.

Answer (score 8):

Check that you created a .yml file in your repo, like they did it [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda).

> The environment.yml file should list all Python libraries on which
>   your notebooks depend, specified as though they were created using the
>   following conda commands:

```
source activate example-environment
conda env export --no-builds -f environment.yml
```

Comment: I had to add a `--from-history` flag. My command was `conda env export --no-builds --from-history -f environment.yml`

Comment: Though this had to be during the same terminal/command-prompt session as the one where I did my `pip install`s and `conda install`s.